# How to install Swagger on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, swagger

I want to install Swagger on Ubuntu.
I am new to swagger.
I want to do some api documentation by using swagger.
For that what are things i need to install on my machine?
Please send me the information as soon as possible.

Comment: ubuntu version ?

Comment: i am using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: can you sent some documentation? if you have

Comment: Refer it : http://blog.programster.org/ubuntu-14-04-installing-swagger. This will work for ubuntu 16.04 also

Comment: i am trying to start npm it shows Please include the following file with any support request

Comment: Have you tried with "sudo" ?

Comment: Which one of the [Swagger projects](https://swagger.io/open-source-integrations/) are you trying to install?

Comment: i tried sudo also

Comment: the first one of the given link

Answer (score 10):

1. install node and npm, you just download node.tar.gz file,can scan node official website, https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/
2. unrar this file,and set global parms for npm and node,if node -v and npm -v has result,it shows you succeed
3. `npm install -g http-server`
4. `git clone https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor.git`
5. `http-server -p 8080 swagger-editor`
6. then you can access http:127.0.0.1:8080 view swagger!!!
   hope can help you !remember give me a good evaluation!

Answer (score 7):

If you are using docker, simply pull and run the [swaggerapi/swagger-editor](https://hub.docker.com/r/swaggerapi/swagger-editor)

```
docker pull swaggerapi/swagger-editor
docker run -p 80:8080 swaggerapi/swagger-editor
```

Open your browser to http://localhost:80/

*Note, make sure your browser does not silently redirect to https://localhost:80/*

Like [rugby2312](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6745734/rugby2312) mentions, you can optionally pass in an existing swagger.json.

```
mkdir tmp
cp swagger.json /tmp/swagger.json
docker run -d -p 80:8080 -v $PWD/tmp:/tmp -e SWAGGER_FILE=/tmp/swagger.json swaggerapi/swagger-editor
```

Comment: As I have already lamp server running, I run container with: docker run -d -p 8080:8080 swaggerapi/swagger-editor to avoid error

Comment: If you want to pass an existing `swagger.json` to the container , remember to do the folder mapping and declare the file name as a variable      `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v /home/ubuntu/dswagger:/tmp -e SWAGGER_FILE=/tmp/swagger.json swaggerapi/swagger-editor`